# How to express AI area ownership?

Tags: unity, ai

Situation:

- Big open world-ish level
- Different types of real estate:

  - Houses including some land around it
  - Just houses without land
  - Flats on different floors

How to express AI ownership of any of those types that I could use in game logic?

---

My first thought was to use collider around the area as a trigger that I could use to detect if "guest" enters the area and program AI to only react if certain criteria is met (e.g sees the guest, friend *vs* enemy) but:

- Most areas are pretty complex - I would need to use mesh colliders
- It would get rather expesive if I had many areas around the player active (urban environment)
- I also need the concept of "my area" for other logic - e.g pathfinding, place items etc